# How to fix the conflict between mySuggestBox.addKeyDownHandler & mySuggestBox.addSelectionHandler in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a SuggestBox. I want 2 things:

-1st, when user Type in a word if the SuggestOracle suggest any word & then if i select that word by hitting the Enter key on the selected word or clicking on that word it will call a methodX

-2st, suppose I typed a word into a suggest &  SuggestOracle suggests NO word, then I want that when I hit Enter key it will fire methodX

This below code met the 1st requirement.

```
getView().getSuggestBox().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent event) {


        methodX();
    }

});
```

This below code met the 2nd requirement.

```
getView().getSuggestBox().addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {

        if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
            methodX();
        }
    }

});
```

However, if i use both of them, then I got this problem.

FOr example, When I type "car" the suggest oracle show "car insurance" "car buy" & then when I use arrow down key to select "car buy" & hit the Enter key, then the system call `methodX("car");` not "`methodX("car buy")`"

WHat is the problem? I think they got conflict or something

How to fix it?

Comment: There is no need to add `KeyDownHandler` that is already handled by `SelectionHandler` when any item is selected via mouse click or enter key.

Comment: use `suggestionBox.getText()` to get the value in the Handler and try with `KeyPressHandler` or `KeyUpHandler`  if it doesn't work instead of `KeyDownHandler` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to add a ValueChangeHandler to the [ValueBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html)

```
getView().getSuggestBox()getValueBox().addValueChangehandler( ... );
```

As far as I remember, this event is triggered, if you hit enter in the Box.

Comment: the thing is that I got validation code in methodX, if suggestBox is empty then it will pop up a message, so if i do like you suggested then each time i click the suggestbox it popup a err message. Can u find a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to register two handlers. This can be achieved by single handler as shown below that will be fired event value is selected via mouse click or by pressing enter key.

```
suggestionBox.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<SuggestOracle.Suggestion>() {

    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {
        System.out.println("selection changed :" + event.getSelectedItem().getDisplayString());
        methodX();
    }
});
```

If nothing works then try with below handler.

```
suggestionBox.getValueBox().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        System.out.println("value changed :" + event.getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried to use just 1 handler suggestionBox.addSelectionHandler & the result is that, if I type "cat" & SuggestOracle show nothing & then if I hit Enter, nothing happened cos there is NoValueChange

Comment: if I use .addValueChangeHandler only then if SuggestOracle suggest any text & if i hit Enter to select it then it didnot  capture the suggested text

Comment: like i said, if i use both then if i hit enter it only capture the old text not the text taken from the suggested list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use a custom SelectionHandler class,  and play with

```
getDisplayString and getReplacementString
```

here is a quick copy/paste of my code:

```
public class SearchStuff Composite implements SelectionHandler<ItemSuggestion> {

    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<ItemSuggestion> event) {

    System.out.println(" getDisplayString( )     = " + event.getSelectedItem().getDisplayString()) ;

    System.out.println("getReplacementString( ) = " + event.getSelectedItem().getReplacementString());


}


public class ItemSuggestion implements IsSerializable, com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestOracle.Suggestion{ 
    @Override
    public String getReplacementString() {
      ....
    }
}
```